# Error while processing request on Azure

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-android-sdk

I have an app connected with Azure backend. I created a login and some api calls 2 months ago. They worked fine until a few days ago and then it starts to fail "sometimes".

 The login log onFailure says: *Error while authenticating user*

 The callback log onFailure says: *Error while processing request*

 And the cause of both says : *stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR*

This post is to similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650333/error-while-processing-request-in-azuremobile-apps-http2-error) but didn't work.

Some code here:

**LoginFragment.java**

```
    private void login(String email, String password){

    loginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    try {

        JsonObject params = new JsonObject();
        params.addProperty("Username", email);
        params.addProperty("Password", password);
        ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> listenable = Client.logIn(getContext(), params);

        Futures.addCallback(listenable, new FutureCallback<MobileServiceUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(MobileServiceUser mobileServiceUser) {
                loginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Client.MS_USER,0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                Client.clientId = mobileServiceUser.getUserId();
                Client.token = mobileServiceUser.getAuthenticationToken();
                editor.putString(Client.MS_USER_ID, Client.clientId);
                editor.putString(Client.MS_AUTH_TOKEN, Client.token);
                editor.apply();

                Client.getInstance(getContext()).setCurrentUser(mobileServiceUser);

                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                loginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Throwable t2 = t.getCause();
                Throwable t3 = t2.getCause();
                Log.e("LoginFail", t.getMessage());
                Log.e("LoginFail", t2.getMessage());
                if(t3 != null){
                    Log.e("LoginFail", t3.getMessage());
                }
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.bad_login), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client {
public static final String MS_USER = "MS_USER";
public static final String MS_USER_ID = "MS_USER_ID";
public static final String MS_AUTH_TOKEN = "MS_AUTH_TOKEN";

public static String clientId;
public static String token;



private static MobileServiceClient instance = null;



public static MobileServiceClient getInstance(Context context) {

    if (instance ==null){
        try {
            instance = new MobileServiceClient(Env.AZURE_URL, context);
            instance.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(() -> {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                client.setWriteTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                return client;
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   } else{
        instance.setContext(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> logIn(Context context, JsonObject parameters) throws MalformedURLException {
    String deviceID = "gcm:" + Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    parameters.addProperty("device_id", deviceID);
    parameters.addProperty("device_dateTime", Env.DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()));
    parameters.addProperty("device_timeZone", API.getTimezone());
    parameters.addProperty("device_language", Env.LANGUAGE);
    parameters.addProperty("app", Env.APP_NAME);

    return getInstance(context).login("auth", parameters);
}

public static  ListenableFuture<JsonElement> callApi(Context context, String apiName, JsonObject parameters, String httpMethod){

    if(httpMethod.equals("POST")){
        String deviceID = "gcm:" + Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        parameters.addProperty("user_id", Client.clientId);
        parameters.addProperty("device_id", deviceID);
        parameters.addProperty("device_dateTime", Env.DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()));
        parameters.addProperty("device_timeZone", API.getTimezone());
        parameters.addProperty("device_language", Env.LANGUAGE);
        parameters.addProperty("app", Env.APP_NAME);
        parameters.addProperty("role", "Patient");
        return getInstance(context).invokeApi(apiName, parameters, httpMethod, null);
    } else {
        return getInstance(context).invokeApi(apiName, null, httpMethod, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to [an issue in Azure App Service](https://github.com/NightscoutFoundation/xDrip/issues/380#issuecomment-378511493) that is weirdly enough not reported on the public Azure status page.

The message that affected Azure client received was (quoted from the link above):

> Starting at 02:00 UTC on 3 Apr 2018, you have been identified as a
>   customer using App Services who may have received connection failure
>   notifications when using Android apps with older HTTP clients or
>   desktop browsers using cross-site scripting calls. Engineers have
>   identified an issue with a recent deployment and are investigating
>   mitigation options. Customers experiencing this issue can
>   self-mitigate by updating the site config setting "http20Enabled" to
>   false via resources.azure.com. Instructions on how to update site
>   config can be found here:
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/
>
> Go to https://resources.azure.com/
>
> Make sure you are in Read/Write mode by clicking in the option to the
>   left of your name.
>
> Find the affected site and browse to Config > Web:
>   https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/sites//config/web
>
> Change the property: "http20Enabled": from true to false by clicking
>   in Edit properties, Update to “false” and then clicking PUT to save
>   change.
>
> If you have tried these steps and are continuing to experience issues
>   with your App Service, please create a technical support ticket to
>   further troubleshoot: aka.ms/azsupt. This message will be closed in 7
>   days.

Comment: I have all like azure says but no result. Probably is related with that but i don't know what can be.  If you have another suggestion I'll be glad to hear you.Thanks anyway.